# How to call a function from kendoListView template

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-template, kendo-listview

Anyone can teach me how to pass the username which come from "myData" to myFunction?
For example "myData" got a username call "jack", how to pass the "jack" to myfunction?

```
myData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
   transport: {
   read: function (options) {
      options.success(arrData);}
   }
});

$($element).find('.slakeNotice').kendoListView({
   dataSource: myData,
   template: '<tr><td>' + myFunction(username) +' </td></tr>'
}).data("kendoListView");

function myFunction(name){
   return xxx;
}
```

I tried several method, but no luck.

```
template: '<tr><td>' + myFunction(username) +' </td></tr>'
```

get username not defined.

```
template: '<tr><td>' + myFunction("username") +' </td></tr>'
```

or

```
 template: '<tr><td>' + myFunction("#=username#") +' </td></tr>'
```

just get a string in my function.

I also tried with:

```
template: '<tr><td>#=myFunction(username)#</td></tr>'
```

But get myFunction not defined.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like,

```
    var getTemplate = function (e) {
        // put a breakpoint here and inspect 'e' (data item)
        return '<tr><td>' + e.username + ' </td></tr>'
    }

    $($element).find('.slakeNotice').kendoListView({
        dataSource: [{ id: 1, username: 'asd' }, { id: 2, username: 'asd' }],
        template: getTemplate
    }).data("kendoListView");
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help :-).